# Rspec: let does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have some Rspec tests, where I'm initialising variables with `let`:

```
  describe 'methods' do

    let(:order)   { Order.new }
    let(:event_1) { FactoryGirl.create(:event) }
    let(:event_2) { FactoryGirl.create(:event) }

    context 'should checks if any event is paid' do
      order.events << event_1
      order.events << event_2
      order.events_paid?.should == true
    end

    context 'should write aasm state' do
      order.aasm_write_state('new')
      order.state.CanonicalName.should == 'new'
    end

  end
```

But I get an error `'method_missing': 'order' is not available on an example group (e.g. a 'describe' or 'context' block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. 'it' blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. 'before', 'le', etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)`

Why the `let` initialising is not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two mistakes:

- you havent wrapped your test within an `it` block (!)
- you try to associate events to `order` but `order` is not persisted

---

Sidenote, the convention is now to use the following syntax:

```
expect(order.events_paid?).to be true
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, I've change the name of  `order` variable but I still get same error

Comment: ah, just realized what the issue was... check the edited answer

Comment: this is the quintessential stackoverflow answer.. "multiple things are wrong with your question and oh by the way the api has changed so go update your code"

Comment: @web-student-ksu :) and I get downvoted answers because api changes and I dont update every single answer of mine!

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: change `context` to `it` and it will work.

---

The problem here is that `context` defines an example group, not an example.  Example groups and examples are fundamentally different; an example group is a class which is used to group examples with common setup code, and an example runs as an instance of that class.  When you use `let`, you are defining a method that is accessible from examples defined in the same example group.  `it` is the main method for defining examples.

See the [note on scope](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core#a-word-on-scope) in the rspec-core README for more info.

On a side note, I wrote the error message you're getting to try to explain this, but clearly it's not achieving that purpose.  What do you find confusing about the error message? How can we make it better so that other users don't trip up over this?